# Django filter based on custom function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filters

I have a table **AvailableDates** with a column **date** that stores date information.
I want to filter the date after performing some operation on it which is defined by **convert_date_to_type** function, that takes parameter input_variable provided by user.

```
def convert_date_to_type(date,input_variable):
   #perform some operation on date based on input_variable
   #return value will be a type, which will be any one item from types list below
   return type
```

list of types:

```
types = []
types.append('type1')
types.append('type2')
types.append('type3')
```

Now I want to filter the table based on type. I will do this in for loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(types)):
   #filter table here based on types[i], something like this
   AvailableDates.objects.filter(convert_date_to_type(date,input_variable)=types[i])
```

How can I achieve this? Any other approach is much appreciated.

I cannot store the **type** information in separate column, because one date can be of different types based on **input_variable** given by user.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are taking will result in very time consuming queries because you are looping over all the objects and therefore skipping all the 
time benefits that Database systems give in terms of querying.

The main question you have to answer is "How frequently is this query going to be used ?"

If it's going to be a lot, then I will suggest the following approach.

1. Creating an extra column or a table with one-to-one relation with your model
2. Override the model's save function to process your date and store the result in this extra column created in step 1 at the time of saving your model.
3. Implement your query on this extra column created in step 1.

This approach has space overhead, but it will make the query faster.

If it's not going to be lot, but the query can make your web request noticeably slow, then also use the above approach. It will help with a smooth web experience.

Comment: All of the above steps can be easily coded by following django's documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that a date can be of different types, based on some input_variable given by the user, so I can't have only a single column to store type information.  I have updated the question.

Comment: To avoid calculating these types from scratch every time you query, you have got to find a way to store the results in database. That's how you can make your query faster.

Comment: If the return type is fixed for the **input_variable**, and input_variable can only be a value from a finite set, then you can create these mappings in the extra table. The only difference is that this extra table will have many-to-one relation with **AvailableDates**. Now, you can construct your query based on the given **input_variable**

Comment: I have already thought of this approach, and i'm going to use it if nothing else comes up.

Comment: @DUDE_MXP Just out of curiosity, what are you using this query for ? It may be possible that whatever approach you are taking is quite complex and there might exist some workaround that makes your query faster.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to get the ids list first:

```
dates_, wanted_ids = AvailableDates.objects.all(), []

for i in range(0, len(types)):
    wanted_ids += [d for d in dates_ if convert_date_to_type(d.date) == types[i]]

wanted_dates = AvailableDates.objects.filter(id__in=wanted_ids)
```

not very performant but it works

Comment: Agreed, but this will be a huge performance overhead, so can't implement this.

Comment: not really huge performance overhead. `dates_` is cached & you can filter that too and you will do only once `filter()` unlike your code in every loop. the only thing is the list that is in memory, but this is also solvable